# private[data] object FormUtils, what is that data?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Just a little question here.
I found on Play Framework 2 sources:

```
private[data] object FormUtils {
   ...
}
```

Just wonder what the [data] means? Is it just some fancy syntax to say the object / class belongs to a subfolder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that this class can only be used from package `play.api.data` and its subpackages. It's close to package-private visibility level in Java, but with two differences:

1. It's visible from subpackages (there are no subpackages in Java, but in Scala, e.g. `play.api.data.foo` is considered a part of `play.api.data`).
2. You can write, e.g. `private[api]`, and it would be visible from all subpackages of `play.api`.

[This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-scala07298/index.html) explains Scala access modifiers in more detail.